# Is there a way to get supported baud rates in C?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, baud-rate

I have an application talking between the PC and a board with a microcontroller running uCLinux. When I send a message over the `/dev/TTYS0` I get it on the PC side, however the message comes across as gibberish. I'm pretty sure that I have a baud rate mismatch of some sort.

On the PC side I'm using the baud rate provided:

```
Serial<id=0x1efb320, open=True>(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='
N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

On the Linux board side I'm setting the same baud rate in the code:

```
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, 9600);
cfsetospeed(&options, 9600);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
tcgetattr(fd, &options);
```

This worked for me when I was testing a PC (Win 7)->Linux Box (OpenSuse) so I know the theory is sound. Now that I've ported this to my true target (coldfire microcontroller board running uCLinux) I'm getting garbage.

So my first option is to "guess and check" at various baud rates to see if I can find one that will work, but rather than that I'd like to programmatically find a way to identify the supported baud rates of a specific target.

I'm sure there's some API, but I haven't found one. Ideas?

**EDIT:**
Seems it's possible to get *max* baud rate on Windows with the [COMMPROP structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363189(v=vs.85).aspx). Does anything even like this exist on Linux?

Comment: Have you checked the default serial port settings in your uClinux box have the same bytesize, parity and stop bits than the PC? In such case you should also set those parameters. I work with uClinux for Coldfire too and I found no problems using the default serial driver...Also remember not having conflicts with the system's console. I mean, in my board /dev/ttyS0 is used by the system shell as the stdout.

Comment: The baud rate is very unlikely to be an issue.  Almost the whole world supports 9600 baud. Much more likely is a bug in your uC code or config data.

Comment: @Claudix - Where can I check those parameters?

Comment: @MartinJames - Regardless, the question still stands. I'd like to be able to add this in as a sanity check in the start of the code. Print out `supported baud rates are: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [`cfsetospeed()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/cfsetospeed.3.html) man page. The `speed` parameter must be a constant: `B50`, `B75`, .., `B9600`, `B19200`, `B38400`, `B57600`, `B115200`, or `B230400`, not just the rate as a number.

To find out if a specific rate is supported, just set it `cfset?speed()`+`tcsetattr()`, then read back the settings (using `tcgetattr()`+`cfget?speed()`), and check if the speed was set to the desired value or not. The driver should reject invalid baud rates, I believe.